# Использование LayoutTransition

Tags: android

Как можно с помощью  `LayoutTransition` анимировать изменение  размера вьюшки?

Comment: а зачем именно при помощи `LayoutTransition`? Почему не при помощи обычной анимации?

Comment: а чем плох LayoutTransition ?